# Entity framework, InvalidOperationException when removing and adding object twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6, database first.

I have a database table called SubstanceNumbers and a datagrid together with a textbox and some other gui elements for adding new entries, the SubstanceNumber have a foreign key field to a Substance.

The scenario that gives me a crash is when I add a SubstanceSubstance, delete it, add it and delete it again, not the most common use case, but I feel like it reveals some larger mistake I've done.

```
My error message: System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Message=Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'SHMD_Edit.Models.EF.SubstanceNumber' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.
```

When I add the SubstanceNumbers, I don't want to set the primary key field SubstanceNumberId, because the database should handle the auto-incrementing, so that will be 0 until I actually context.SaveChanges().

My add/delete commands look like this:

```
public RelayCommand AddSubstanceNumberCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(
                (x) =>
                {
                    var number = new SubstanceNumber();
                    number.SubstanceID = Id;
                    number.ModifiedBy = Main.op.LoginName;
                    number.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    number.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    number.Type = Converters.NumberTypeToStringConverter.translation.First(t => t.Value == SelectedNewSubstanceNumberType).Key;
                    number.NumberText = Validator.Normalize(NewSubstanceNumber, SelectedNewSubstanceNumberType);
                    var temp = NewSubstanceNumber.Replace("-", "");
                    number.NumberValue = Int32.Parse(temp.Substring(0, temp.Length - 1));
                    if (NewSubstanceNumber != null && !SubstanceNumbers.Any(sn => sn.NumberText.Replace(" ", "") == number.NumberText && sn.Type == number.Type))
                        SubstanceNumbers.Add(number);

                    NewSubstanceNumber = "";

                }, param => this.CanAddSubstanceNumber);
        }
    }
```

and

```
public RelayCommand RemoveSubstanceNumberCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(
                (x) =>
                {
                    if (SelectedSubstanceNumber != null)
                    {
                        context.Entry(SelectedSubstanceNumber).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                        SubstanceNumbers.Remove(SelectedSubstanceNumber);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

My table:

```
Column name, Data Type, Allow Nulls (is identity, identity increment=1)
SubstanceNumberID   int Unchecked
SubstanceID int Unchecked
Type    int Unchecked
NumberText  char(16)    Unchecked
NumberValue int Unchecked
CreatedDate datetime    Unchecked
ModifiedDate    datetime    Unchecked
ModifiedBy  nvarchar(16)    Unchecked
RowVersion  timestamp   Unchecked
```

So I assume there is some synchronization error between the context and my list of SubstanceNumbers, but I can't see what it is. Can you point it out?

Comment: Make sure the primary key is set to auto-increment in your database.

Comment: It would be relevant to show what SubstanceNumbers is as well as when/where you do a Context.SaveChanges(). Mind updating your post with these details please?

Comment: I added the table info, I do Context.SaveChanges() when the user clicks a Save button, so there is no save involved in my scenario for this post.

Answer (score 0):

When you are deleting do something like this.

```
public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(typeof(T) + " cannot be null.");


            try
            {
                DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _DbContext.Entry(entity);
                if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
                {
                    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }
                else
                {
                    _DbSet.Attach(entity);
                    _DbSet.Remove(entity);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    throw;
            }

        }
```

This is a generic method from a generic class but you can get the picture. Before removing check the state of the entity. If it's state is not deleted change the state to deleted. If the state is deleted attach it and remove it.

Comment: Every time I do this, the entry state will be != deleted, so I'll always set the state to deleted, leading to the exception being thrown. I'm also a bit sceptical about using try-catch as a sort of normal mode of operation like this. Deleting something twice should not lead to any raised exceptions at all.